# How can I extract a specific Image from an Icon file in .NET?

Tags: .net, image, gdi+, icons

Icon files (*.ico) may contain multiple images at different sizes and of different colour depths.

How can I obtain a `System.Drawing.Image` object from a `.ico` file?

One option is `Image.FromFile(...)`, but for icon files with multiple images there is no way to specify which image size and colour depth to return.

Ideally the solution would use only managed code, but I'm happy to hear about interop calls to Win32 functions as well.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer to all your questions: [IconLib](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconLib.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this link.  Looks like a great article.  I don't need this any more, but next time I work with icons, I'll definitely check this library out.  Hope your answer helps out others too.  It's the best answer so far, so I've accepted it, though if a simpler answer comes along that doesn't require external libraries, I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

System.Drawing.Icon can load a specified size from a file. I don't know about depth, though.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142130.aspx

Comment: Except for sizes above 48x48, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use

```
Dim icon As System.Drawing.Icon
icon = icon.FromHandle(hIcon)
```

In the hIcon structure you can specify the color depth

This links will guide you in the right direction:

- http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial219_Extracting-Icons-from-Files.html
- http://bytes.com/groups/net/120863-system-drawing-icon-hicon-ptr-iconimage-structure