# How can I extract multiple sized images from an .ICO embedded on a .resources file?

Tags: .net, image, icons, embedded-resource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I extract a specific Image from an Icon file in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510717/how-can-i-extract-a-specific-image-from-an-icon-file-in-net)

I have a file, "multi.ico" which has four images of different sizes (16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48).  Each sized image is a different color, to make it easy to tell which size we are dealing with.  This file has been inserted into a resource file "Multi.resources" using Lutz Roeder's .NET Resourcer.

I need to be able to extract the ico from the .resource file in such a way as to keep all four sizes of images.  Ideally, I would like to have a wrapper class around the .ico object which allows selection of the image of the proper size.

I have a working wrapper that I can use with a standalone .ico file (multi.ico), but my company system has a lot of images, and we need to be able to bundle them into .resource files for distribution.

Can anybody show me a piece of code which would take a .resources file extract the 16x16 version of an embedded .ico file.  I can't seem to get at anything but the 32x32 sized image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510717/how-can-i-extract-a-specific-image-from-an-icon-file-in-net